# Browser specific hosts file

Tags: browser, hosts

I have a web application that I am working on, and we have three servers - Production, Staging(QA), and Dev.

Is there a way to have a specific browser point to on server, and another browser point to a different server? IE: Firefox points to Production, Safari to Staging, and Chrome to Dev?

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out:

`navigator.appName` resolves to "Microsoft Internet Explorer", not "Internet Explorer" like you have written.

Also, the first character `navigator.appVersion` will not provide you with the version of the browser. In IE 10, it resolves to "5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0;"

To make your code work, you need to update it to something like:

```
function get_browser_version(){
  var N=navigator.appName, ua=navigator.userAgent, tem;
  var M=ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
  if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
  M=M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
  return M[1];
}

var browser = navigator.appName;
var version = get_browser_version();

if (browser=="Microsoft Internet Explorer") { 
    if (version<="8.1") 
        document.location.href="lores.htm" 
}
```